# Error 500 - module error

Tags: magento2, php, http-error-500

We get a strange issue with, for me, it looks like it might be a missing closing  tag, however, I can't see any missing closing tags.

PHPerror.log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given in /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/JsFooterPlugin.php:44
```

Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/JsFooterPlugin.php(44): strpos(NULL, '</body')
#1 /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\JsFooterPlugin->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#2 /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#3 /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#4 /chroot/home/ae in /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/JsFooterPlugin.php on line 44
[15-Oct-2021 12:52:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given in /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/JsFooterPlugin.php:44
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/JsFooterPlugin.php(44): strpos(NULL, '</body')
#1 /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\JsFooterPlugin->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#2 /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#3 /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#4 /chroot/home/ae in /chroot/home/ae89d724/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/JsFooterPlugin.php on line 44

Comment: Check which variable returns null; then search where she come from. Without any code it's hard to tell.

Comment: Previosly have you perform anything? And after that above issue occured?